# Is it possible to filter Elements Collection more?

Tags: selenium, selenide

I get one table row from page with this code

```java
ElementsCollection letters = $$("#myIdName tr").filterBy(Condition.text(email))
```

And I want to select and click one td href element from that row. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use .get(i) function:

```
$$("#myIdName tr").filterBy(Condition.text(email)).get(0).click()
```

or if you know how you filtered it, you can also use `.first()` or `.last()`

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a `<td>` element, then simply use it in your collection's locator:

```
$$("#myIdName td")
```

You'll get a collection of all the cells from your table. After that, just do the same thing that you did before (e.g. filter by cell's text and do the click on it):

```
$$("#myIdName td").filterBy(text(email)).click()
```